# Python3 read file and assigning the output

Tags: python

i have test.txt file containing this value,

```
11a,22a,33a,44a
11b,22b,33b,44b
```

how to read and assign the output to variable, like this,,

```
a1 = 11a
a2 = 22a
a3 = 33a
```

thanks alot

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Python read file", you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this to get started:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    first_line = f.readline().split(",")
    a1 = first_line[0]
    a2 = first_line[1]
    a3 = first_line[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use a dictionary here to avoid manually creating all variable names

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    content =  [line.strip() for line in f]

content = [j for i in content for j in i.split(',')]
dct = {i[::-1][:2]: i for i in content}

print(dct)
# {'a1': '11a', 'a2': '22a', 'a3': '33a', 'a4': '44a', 'b1': '11b', 'b2': '22b', 'b3': '33b', 'b4': '44b'}
```